# $X$ taken from $N(0,\theta)$ .Doubt related to MLE and Sufficient statistic

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, statistical-inference, maximum-likelihood

Let $X$ be a single observation from $N(0,\theta).\ \ (\theta=\sigma^2)$

Writing joint density.
$L(x;\theta)=\dfrac{e^{-\frac{x^2}{2\theta}}}{\sqrt{2\pi\theta}}=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\theta}}\cdot e^{-\frac{x^2}{2\theta}}$

We see that $T(X)=X^2$ sufficient for $\theta$

**$(a)$ Is $X$ is sufficient statistic?**

Since the original sample is always sufficient we conclude that $X$ is sufficient.

**$(b)$ Is $|X|$ is sufficient statistic?**

$|X|=\sqrt{X^2}$

I am stuck in this one. So please guide me here.

**$(c)$ Is $X^2$ is sufficient statistic?**

Yes, that's what we get from Neymann Factorization theorem.

**$(d)$ What is the maximum likelihood estimator of $\sqrt{\theta}$**

When $X \sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ MLE of $\sigma^2$is $\dfrac{\sum_{i}(X_i-\bar{X})^2}{n}$

in our case, we have $\dfrac{X^2-0}{1}$

using invariance property MLE of $\sqrt{\theta}$ is $\sqrt{X^2}=X$

B part is where I am stuck and I want to know if I calculated everything right? Where I am going wrong? Any tips to keep in mind and please correct me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(a) is wrong. You found with factorization theorem that $T=X^2$ is sufficient for $\sigma^2$. $X$ is not sufficient because it is NOT a monotonic function of $T$

(b)

$$T_1=|X|=\sqrt{X^2}$$

In this case, $|X|$ is a monotonic function of $T$ thus $T_1$ is sufficient too for $\sigma^2$

(c) this is wrong too...

Easy find that $\hat{\theta}=X^2$ (observe that MLE must be function of the sufficient estimator, if it exists)

Now using invariance property

$$\hat{\sigma}_{ML}=\sqrt{\hat{\theta}}=|X|$$

Comment: For part A  there is only one sample and I read that the original sample is sufficient always. Why it's not sufficient I don't understand? Before even using any theorem to find sufficient statistics first part should be right isnt it?

Comment: @Daman I do not know where you read that but surely $X \in \mathbb{R}$ cannot be a good estimator for $\theta>0$

Comment: @Daman : these are very nice lectures inclduding Sufficiency, ancillary, completeness and so on https://ani.stat.fsu.edu/~debdeep/5327_s15.html

Comment: Thanks tommik I am having very hard time understanding these concepts.